# Magento 2 - dynamic (not cached) prices

Tags: magento2

**Background:**

1. My e-commerce is available for logged customers only
2. Each customer has different product prices because different discounts are applied.
3. Products prices have to been calculated on fly based on current customer's discounts.
4. Full Page Cache will be enabled

How to implement the pricing so that they are not being cached?

My idea is using Knockout: send `product id` and `customer id` to API service which will calculate price and send back to JS Component. Make sense?

Thanks

Comment: You also need to intercept the price in the backend php code, just changing the displayed price on frontend won't effect the actual item price.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. Will the plugin afterGetPrice on Product model do the work for me?

Comment: Yes, that should work.